# Can boost 1.54 install with libboost_thread-mt.so like library files using apt-get install libboost-all-dev command

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, boost

When installing boost in Ubuntu 13.10 I used

> apt-get install libboost-all-dev

command. In this case library files which are ending with **-mt.so (such like libboost_thread-mt.so, libboost_system-mt.so, libboost_filesystem-mt.so, and so on)** cannot be found. Installed version of boost is 1.54 so can I verify whether the mentioned library files (**such like libboost_thread-mt.so, libboost_system-mt.so, libboost_filesystem-mt.so, and so on**) are available with boost 1.54 default installation(**apt-get install liboost-all-dev**).

Comment: this wasn't duplicate at the time I asked the question. Anyway I found the answer.